# How do I find out if a number is an integer in this expression?

Tags: java, if-statement, numbers, integer

I'm trying to determine if a number is an integer in an expression like this. (10 * 2) + 5. If the expression was (10 * 2) + 5.24 I want the program to say that there's a non-integer in that expression. Current code:

```
public static boolean isInt(String expr) {
    for (int i = 0; i<expr.length(); i++){
        if (expr. charAt(i) != (int)i){
        return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that there are a lot more characters besides just numbers. So I want it to just check the numbers and ignore all the other symbols to determine if every number in the string is an integer.

Comment: if (expr.contains ("."))

Comment: Does the expression will have only numbers, and other characters like ()+*, right? Or wrong inputs(alphabets) also?

Comment: To evaluate a numerical expression including mathematical operations try using the ScriptEngine class as shown in the green arrow reply at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java.  To use Java to evaluate it would involve writing a class that does it to an external file, then  compiling and running its jar as an external executable.

Comment: If you find any of these resolve your problem, you should mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by tokenizing into "words", splitting on * /+-()^ and blank spaces. The results should just be numbers, if I understand what you're doing.

To split using Guava:
Iterable tokens = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("- /*+()^")).split(myExpression);

Then you can scan the "words" looking for a decimal point as suggested by @Scary Wombat

Here is a complete version:

```
public void test() {

    char[] values = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    List<Character> ints = Chars.asList(values);

    String str = "the values are 4 and 4.03 tons";
    Iterable<String> tokens = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("- /*+()^")).split(str);

    for (String token : tokens) {
        char[] chars = token.toCharArray();
        for (char c : chars) {
            if (!ints.contains(c)) {
                System.out.println(token + " is not an int");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Producing:

```
the is not an int
values is not an int
are is not an int
and is not an int
4.03 is not an int
tons is not an int
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this can meet your needs

```
String str = "the values are 4 and 4.03 tons";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+[.]?\\d*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    String ss = m.group();
    int temp_i;
    try {
        temp_i = Integer.parseInt(ss);
        System.out.println(temp_i);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s not integer", ss));
    }//end try
}//end while
```

Or, to cater for float such as 3e-2, use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+[.eE]?[-]?\\d*");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it with reg expression.

```
String regExp = "([0-9]*\\.[0-9]*)";
```

And then count the no: of matches with each equality found.

So,
the complete code is here:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class RegExpDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regExp = "([0-9]*\\.[0-9]*)";
        String input = "-1 + 5 - (10 * 2) + 5.24 / (3.146 * 22 / 100)";
        try {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
            int count = 0;
            while(matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Result "+matcher.group());
                count++;
                //System.out.println("Count "+matcher.groupCount());    
            }   
            System.out.println("Total Count "+count);           
        } catch(Exception exp) {
            System.out.println(exp);
        }
    }
}
O/p
--------------
Result 5.24
Result 3.146
Total Count 2
```

I hope the input contains only valid number formats and any other characters are not used. ie; 1,26 instead of 1.26. If any other characters, you may need to modify the pattern depending on that

Also if you need to count values like 1..26 then use quantifier + with .(dot)

```
        String regExp = "([0-9]*\\.+[0-9]*)";
        String input = "-1 + 5 - (10 * 2) + 5.24 / (3.146 * 22 / 100) - 1..26";
```